# libxml/parser.h: in c++ ubuntu

Tags: c++

Even though I have installed libxml++2.6-2 libxml++2.6-doc etc in my ubuntu 12.04 version again I am getting the below error 
        fatal error: libxml/parser.h: No such file or directory
I am using make for building the project

```
     Kindly suggest any other libxml libraries which I need to install
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before Posting the answer THANKS to the people who have answered, but those answers were not worked for me

```
I have just copied libxml folder from the directory usr/lib/libxml2 and pasted in usr/lib directory and compiled my code it is not giving any error. It is working fine now.
```

Comment: Hmm, messing up with the files in your operating system is not really the way to go. Hard to believe the flag -I/usr/include/libxml2 didn't solve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

1. `libxml/parser.h` is a part o `libxml` library, not `libxml++`
2. For any given library, you need development packages (the ones with names ending in `-dev`) in order to build applications using that library.
3. You need to pass additional flags to your compiler: `xml2-config --cflags` and to linker `xml2-config --libs`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to an Ubuntu system now, but: Maybe you need to install the libxml developer package? Maybe you only have the library but not the include file(s)?

Check in `/usr/include`, `/usr/local/include`, ... for the directory `libxml` and the file `parser.h`.

If you find the file, you may need to adapt your makefile so that the parent-directory is in the list of include paths, e.g.:
`INC = -I/usr/local/include
g++ $(INC) ...`

If you did not find the file: Check the available libxml packages for a developer package and install that.

Answer (score 0):

Please read @el.pescado answer before reading this. I wanted to comment on that answer but felt the need to format my code better.

```
gcc -c <files to compile> `xml2-config --cflags` -o <object files>
gcc <object files> -L<libxml2 lib location> `xml2-config --libs` -o <binary file>
```

Assuming we have a file names `xmltest.c` that have code that included `libxml2` header like `#include <libxml/parser.h>`, standard location of `libxml2` shared library i.e. `/usr/lib64/libxml2`, the above code will evaluate like this:

```
gcc -c xmltest.c -I/usr/include/libxml2 -o xmltest.o
gcc xmltest.o -L/usr/lib64/libxml2 -lxml2 -lz -lm -o xmltest
```

A better idea is to put together a `Makefile` that does this automatically.